# Wsl2 - как перенести на другой диск?

Tags: linux, wsl2

Установил Wsl2 вместе с ubuntu на винду 11. По умолчанию она устанавливается на диск С.
Диск С - у меня ссд на 128гигов, установил 1 проект и память закончилась=(
Вопрос: Как можно перенести с диска С на диск D?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Даже при отсутствии средств указания пути для размещения чего либо в 99% работают симлинки

Comment: @vitidev это нужно указать в реестре?

Comment: Это файловая система. Win поддерживает символические ссылки (требуют права админа для создания) и junction point (фича конкретно NTFS, не требуют прав админа). базовые команды в консоли mklink и junction (выпилили в вин 10, но можно [скачать](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/downloads/junction)) ну или куча GUIшных софтин для этого. Хоть всю папку Users переносите (конечно не из самой винды) - все будет работать.